# Problem with grpc running ionic project in a Macbook

Tags: ios, macos, ionic-framework, npm, grpc

I have an ionic app working on Android and now I need to make the iOS version.

At work, they gave me a Mac to do this.

I cloned the project from GitHub and then, I tried to install all the dependencies.

But I have a problem. When I run `npm install` I get:

```
> grpc@1.10.1 install /Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.14.2 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.14.2 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file 
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
rm: ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o.d.raw: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.14.2/bin/node" "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.14.2/bin/node /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.14.2/bin/node" "/Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.14.2/bin/node /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown' (1)
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.oe
In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.cc:19:iled to e
In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.h:22:
../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/exec_ctx.h:23:10: fatal error: 
      'grpc/support/cpu.h' file not found
#include <grpc/support/cpu.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.░⸩ ⠴ install: info lifecycle grpc@1.10.1~install: Failed to e
make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.14.2/bin/node" "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ivanlencina/dev/animaedu/pausa/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-toastr@8.10.2 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
```

I tried to remove node and install it with brew.
I tried to reinstall npm and reinstall that dependency called `grpc` but it still having problems..

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of grpc referenced there (1.10) is old enough that it does not support the version of Node you are using (10). You will need to either downgrade your Node runtime to an older version or get that library to depend on a newer version of grpc in order to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will research about it.

Comment: Solved downgrading node to 8 with brew